# guzzle installation via composer

Tags: php, yii, elasticsearch, composer-php, guzzle

recently I've started one project and want to use `elasticsearch`. But when I want to install `guzzle` for `PHP` via `composer`, I get folowing error. I have no idea what is this error.

[image]

My composer required packages are:

```
"require":{
    "yiisoft/yii":"1.1.14",
    "2amigos/yiiwheels":"1.0.3",
    "clevertech/yii-booster": "4.0.1",
    "drmabuse/yii-bootstrap-3-module": "dev-master",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "3.9.0",
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "1.2.2"
  },
```

my `PHP Version 5.4.7`

my [composer.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wx7h10xxn5mrfjt/composer.json?dl=0) file

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem installing all the packages from your requirements in one go.

If the problem persists, try to delete the vendor folder and the `composer.lock` file and run `composer update` again.

Comment: Yes, I tried that few times, but did not solve the problem. But, when I installed vagrant with CentOS and Nginx instead of Apache, it went without having problems. But problem remains on my dev machine, where I can't use nor vagrant nor Nginx

Comment: When did you last run `composer self-update`? And what else is in your `composer.json` - because I definitely didn't get that "buskamuza" package when I installed your dependencies.

Comment: problem remains after composer self-update. I attached my composer.json file